# Showing that a complex function is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

> Find out, and give reason, whether $f(z)$ is continuous at $z = 0$ if $f(0) = 0$ and for $z\neq 0$ the function $f$ is equal to $(\operatorname{Re}z^2)/|z|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=x+iy$, then $|Re (z^2)|=|x^2-y^2| \le x^2+y^2=|z|^2$, hence, for $z \ne 0$:

$|f(z)| \le |z|$.

This gives $f(z) \to 0=f(0)$ for $z \to 0$.